# How to access values in another column of a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe :

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Salary' : pd.Series([1, 20000, 5, 1000, 3000], 
index = ['Joe', 'Steph', 'Jared', 'Oliver', 'Gaby']),
'Sex' : pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
index=['Joe', 'Steph', 'Jared', 'Oliver', 'Gaby'])})

        Salary  Sex
Joe          1    0
Steph    20000    1
Jared        5    0
Oliver    7000    0
Gaby      3000    1
```

I write a function which takes in a column name as an argument, calculates the interquartile range of the values and returns the number of outliers based on that. If I would also like that function to return the number of females that have salaries that are outliers, how do I access the 'sex' column in order to check the corresponding 'sex' value of an outlier salary?

Here is my outlier function:

```
def iqr_outliers(num_df, column):
    nan_count = 0
    for value in column:
        if value == 'NaN':
            nan_count += 1
   cleaned_column = [x for x in column if str(x) != "NaN"]
   iqr = np.subtract(*np.percentile(cleaned_column, [75, 25]))
   upper =  np.percentile(cleaned_column, 75) + 1.5 * iqr
   lower =  np.percentile(cleaned_column, 25) - 1.5 * iqr
   outliers = []
   lows = 0
   highs = 0
   fem_outliers= 0
   for value in cleaned_column:
      if value < lower:
          lows += 1
         outliers.append(value)
       elif value > upper:
           highs += 1
           outliers.append(value)
    return ({"Number of low outliers": lows, "Number of high outliers": highs, "Number of NaNs": nan_count})
```

Somewhere in those if statements I want to see to check the value of 'sex' for the same row, but I really don't know how to access that.

Comment: You are using `pandas` wrong. See my answer for how you should approach these sorts of things in general.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I am very new to the whole thing.  One thing I am concerned about is how `d.Salary.quantile([.25,.75])` will handle NaNs, I seem to recall something about them simply being put at the end of list.  Do you know anything about this?

Comment: I seem to recall that `quantile` doesn't play nice with NaNs. Usually, for most pandas methods NaNs are ignored by default. You will likely be able to deal with it by using `.dropna`

Comment: Yes, quantile does in fact not play nice.  However, all of my columns (salary included) have NaNs so `.dropna` doesn't work well.  'fillna(0)' is not an option since that will greatly skew where the quartiles are. So I guess this is really an issue of how to use quantile with a NaN heavy dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you can calculate inter-quartile range with `percentile`:

```
In [21]: d
Out[21]:
        Salary  Sex
Joe          1    0
Steph    20000    1
Jared        5    0
Oliver    1000    0
Gaby      3000    1

In [22]: iqr = d.Salary.quantile([.25,.75]).values

In [23]: iqr
Out[23]: array([    5.,  3000.])
```

Then, you can use elementwise boolean operations:

```
In [24]: (d.Salary < iqr[0]) | (d.Salary > iqr[1])
Out[24]:
Joe        True
Steph      True
Jared     False
Oliver    False
Gaby      False
Name: Salary, dtype: bool
```

And finally, you can use the result of that for selection on your entire dataframe:

```
In [26]: d[(d.Salary < iqr[0]) | (d.Salary > iqr[1])]
Out[26]:
       Salary  Sex
Joe         1    0
Steph   20000    1
```

Or something to that effect. I do not recall the specifics of Tukey outliers off hand. But it should be easily tractable with the approach illustrated above.

### Ok, here is what you need using the Tukey test:

```
In [40]: IQR = iqr[1] - iqr[0]

In [41]: upper = 1.5*IQR+iqr[1]

In [42]: lower = iqr[0] - 1.5*IQR

In [43]: (d.Salary < lower) | (d.Salary > upper)
Out[43]:
Joe       False
Steph      True
Jared     False
Oliver    False
Gaby      False
Name: Salary, dtype: bool

In [44]: d[(d.Salary < lower) | (d.Salary > upper)]
Out[44]:
       Salary  Sex
Steph   20000    1
```

To get the number of females, you can just use `sum`

```
In [46]: d[(d.Salary < lower) | (d.Salary > upper)]['Sex'].sum()
Out[46]: 1
```